# Incorrect AWK command

Tags: bash, awk, cat

I had a ~300mb text file full of asterisk calls which needs to be sent to a customer although cannot include specific information,

The only information i would like to extract is as follow;

Everything between the asterisks `*NUMBER#NUMBER,sip-out*`

I was thinking of using a awk similar to `.*#(\d+),sip-out.*` on the file `numbers.txt`

Although my formatting is slightly wrong. any ideas?

The goal is to print out on the screen `\n` in between the above asterisks.

Thanks in advance.

Ashley

Comment: Can you post some sample input and desired output to make it more understandable?

Comment: sample input and output would be more helpful

Comment: Hi Apologies, For example it should only print 123456#624634763,sip-out from masses of text instead of everything, so

if i cat file.txt it would bring back everything, but i would say.. like the results of the cat to only print back all information within the parameters *NUMBER#NUMBER,sip-out*

Comment: @user3327188 - no, don't try to tell us what the file looks like in a comment, update your question to include an actual SAMPLE input file of say 10 lines plus the output you'd like to get given that input file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `gnu awk` (due to RS) will get correct data?

```
awk -v RS=",sip-out" 'NF{print $NF RS}' file
```

cat file

```
some data 123456#624634763,sip-out more data
just 223456#624634763,sip-out more
not this line
1234666#62468883,sip-out
```

gives this

```
123456#624634763,sip-out
223456#624634763,sip-out
1234666#62468883,sip-out
```

If you do not like the `sip-out` text, just remove the `RS` from the `print` like this:

```
awk -v RS=",sip-out" 'NF {print $NF}' file
123456#624634763
223456#624634763
1234666#62468883
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is really help, now just another quick question. it seems to be printing everything up to  the sip-out", 

how could i limit it so it is everything in between the # and the sipout" for example?

Comment: @user3327188 Try this: `awk -v RS=",sip-out" 'NF {i=split($NF,a,"#");print a[i]}'`

Comment: Or this: `awk -v RS=",sip-out" 'NF {sub(/[^#]*#/,"",$NF);print $NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

Using grep with o option.

```
grep -o "\*.*\*" file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -o '\*[0-9]+#[0-9]+,sip-out\*' numbers.txt | tr -d '*'
```

- Uses `egrep -o` to only extract all substrings of interest, including the enclosing `*` chars.
- Then removes the enclosing `*` chars. using `tr`.

Note: With `GNU grep` you could get away with just a `grep` command by using look-around assertions:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\*)[0-9]+#[0-9]+,sip-out(?=\*)' numbers.txt
```